# Why did the men and women in Vandread split up to begin with?

Tags: vandread

I don't know if I'm just misremembering what I saw in the anime, or if there really was no good explanation ever given, but I am unclear on the real reason why the original men and women in the space colony in Vandread split up into two separate colonies in the first place.

So, **do we ever get a real explanation as to why they split by gender, or is it just something we're supposed to take for granted?**

Answer (score 2):

> Once upon a time, in the future (roughly two thousand years from now), a colonist ship departed Earth, heading for the stars on it's journey to discover a new world to populate for the human race. This journey proved successful with the discovery of not one but two neighbouring planets suitable of colonisation. However, the colonists grew into conflict with each other - A conflict that divided the crew by gender! The men settled on one planet, which was dubbed Taraaku while the woman settled for the neighbouring planet, Mejarru.

I couldn't find much to support this but it sounds like something that fits the anime.

[Source](http://www.angelfire.com/anime4/spike558/teach.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Each colony or colony group was created to provide a specific component or body part to the remaining earth humans.  That flotilla that was encountered in space, the one with the weird drink, was created to provide skin, that water planet provided spinal columns, along with nerve tissue and fluid, and the split planets, where our main cast come from, provided reproductive organs/hormonal systems.  They were separated out and instructed to use cloning technology so that the organs would not be used when it was time for harvesting.  The split colony was one of the last to be created, so it wasn't actually ready for harvesting during the series.  But they rebelled, by the actions of our crew, and so the harvesting happened early.

Comment: It looks like you have the start of a good answer here, but can you mention which episodes or chapters this information was given in? Also, it's considered polite to spoiler-tag any important plot information from later in a series; see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to find out how.